# How to add the /tmp folder to Favorites on the Sidebar of Finder?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Can someone let me know if it is possible to add `/tmp` to Favorites on the Sidebar in Finder? If yes can someone provide me the steps?

[image: Favorites on Sidebar n Finder]

- Mac OS = 10.13.6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While in **Finder**...

- Press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to bring up **Go to the folder:**, then type in `/private` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Now preform one or the other of the following actions:

- Select the `tmp` folder and press: <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Or

- Drag the `tmp` folder to **Favorites** in the **Sidebar**.

The first method places the folder at the bottom of the existing **Favorites**, whereas the second method allows one to drag it where one wants. It also can be dragged after the fact to change its position in the **Favorites**.

Both methods have been tested by me to work in OS X Mountain Lion, OS X El Capitan, macOS High Sierra and I see no immediate reason one or the other will not work in other versions of OS X/macOS that actually support this action.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in two easy steps:

- Create a symlink (in your Home Folder for example) and then add that to your favorites

  ```
  $ ln -s /private/tmp ~/Temp\ Folder
  ```
- Then drag that folder to your Favorites in your sidebar.